# What less obvious ways are there to misuse and damage a UPS?

Tags: electrical-power, ups

I've never had an uninterruptible power supply and think of buying one. What not-so-obvious things should I not do to the UPS so that it lives longer?

I don't mean some obvious abuse like dropping/exposing to direct heat/exposing to wrong voltage. I mean less obvious things like its not acceptable to leave an acid battery UPS unplugged for long time after it has been used because some chemical processes start in half-discharged batteries and render the batteries unusable. What other misuses should I know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you have wonky power (flicker flicker) adjust the sensitivity of the UPS so it doesn't trip for every little flicker.  My apartment unit is next to the elevator.  I killed a set of batteries in 8 months this way.

Answer (score 4):

The SLA (sealed lead acid) batteries in UPSes shouldn't be left in a discharged state.  If they are, sulfates will build up on the plates and their capacity will be reduced.  This isn't normally a problem in UPSes, since they're always plugged in and after a power outage will charge the batteries back up when the power comes on.  But if you somehow decided to unplug a UPS after the batteries were drained and then left it sitting unplugged for a week, you'd probably notice the battery discharging sooner next time.

Comment: APC suggests that if you stop using a UPS, you should disconnect the batteries - and that said batteries will last a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Dont overload it.  If it has a nice status screen to see the load on it try to keep it below about 60%

By discharging it faster will wear out the the battery faster

Heat, humidity are also bad for it.

Answer (score 3):

While in college I was moving some servers from one room to another.  They all where on a really old UPS which apparently had less protection circuitry then current UPS equipment.  I started by disconnecting all the servers from the UPS and moving those.  Then without shutting down the UPS I unplugged it from the wall.  Sparks started shooting out of the UPS and it literally started bouncing.

The electronics teacher had a plausible sounding explanation about why something like this would happen given the design of the UPS, but I don't remember enough details to explain it here.

So the moral of the story is this.

- When there is no load, **always** turn off the UPS before disconnecting the power.

Comment: Generally sound advice for all electronic equipment

Answer (score 2):

According to the answers to [my question over here](https://serverfault.com/questions/29288/ups-and-power-strip-interactions), it's a bad idea to have a power strip touch it either upstream or downstream.

Answer (score 2):

Don't plug a UPS into another UPS (i.e. Daisychaining them).

There's a good discussion [on why not to here](http://board.iexbeta.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=64170&view=findpost&p=714620), or from [APC themselves here](http://nam-en.apc.com/cgi-bin/nam_en.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=397&p_created=1010390400&p_sid=Uz4QDwai&p_lva=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MTMmcF9wcm9kcz0wJnBfY2F0cz0mcF9wdj0mcF9jdj0mcF9zZWFyY2hfdHlwZT1hbnN3ZXJzLnNlYXJjaF9ubCZwX3BhZ2U9MSZwX3NlYXJjaF90ZXh0PWRhaXN5IGNoYWlu&p_li=&p_topview=1).

Comment: I have a great story about that .... a 6 UPS dasiychain. We had to turn them off to move equipment. Then no one could figure out which one we needed to turn on first ... That was a great day.

Comment: You're not likely to have one, but I have heard stories of people running a ferroresonant (Sola) transformer through a UPS and literally blowing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Your main concern should be heat. Don't cover it with a bunch of stuff. Keep the vents clear, and allow airflow.